# How to change WebProjectOutputDir default location?

Tags: visual-studio, web-applications, msbuild

Does anybody know, on a per project basis, whether you can set the WebProjectOutputDir in Visual Studio. I want to be able to have it so that when i hit <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>B</kbd> it automatically builds my web project to a specific directory, but I also need to be able to override this in my build script.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

It is ***unnecessarily awkward*** to correctly do this based on the way that `Microsoft.WebApplications.targets` defines the `_CopyWebApplication` target and how `Microsoft.Common.targets` treats the `OutDir` and `OutputPath` properties.

If you want to change that in the project file itself then you should:

- Declare the property `WebProjectOutputDir` after the import to `Microsoft.WebApplications.targets`
- Declare the property `OutDir` before the import to `Microsoft.WebApplications.targets`

**There are a few reasons why you have to do this.**

`Microsoft.WebApplications.targets` will override any declaration of `WebProjectOutputDir` if it is declared before the import statement. Therefore it has to come after.

Also inside of `Microsoft.WebApplications.targets` the `_CopyWebApplication` is defined as follows:

```
<Target Name="_CopyWebApplication" Condition="'$(OutDir)' != '$(OutputPath)'" >
  ....
</Target>
```

Taking a look at the condition you will see that the target will not be executed if `OutDir` and `OutputPath` are equal to the same value. You cannot just change OutputPath because `OutDir` is based on `OutputPath`, so you have to change `OutDir` and make sure that it is before the import to that file because other properties are built based on that property.

Less than ideal, but hopefully that helps you.

Answer (score 7):

I ran into this when using *Visual Studio for Mac*, compiling an *Umbraco* project. Building would issue the following error:

> Error MSB4044: The "KillProcess" task was not given a value for the
>   required parameter "ImagePath"

It was returning an empty value for *WebProjectOutputDir* when compiling Rosyln, etc. Only the web project in the solution was compiling these items, so I edited the web project csproj file manually, and added the following to the global  at the top of the file:

```html
    ...
    <WebProjectOutputDir>.\</WebProjectOutputDir>
</PropertyGroup>
```

Problem solved.

Comment: About time someone actually posted a solution to the "missing" WebProjectOutputDir variable!

Comment: @T.S. the line is just assigning a sane value to the `WebProjectOutputDir` variable, which for some reasons happens to be unset by default.

Comment: I don't understand where this `.\` takes you in relation to a project file or relation to whaever